# OOP or Structural : PHP Web site

Tags: php, mysql, oop, programming-languages

I'll start a new PHP/MySQL web site / Facebook application for Videos - Pictures - Articles sharing, users can share videos from videos hosting web sites, pictures from URL's or Upload, and Articles will be written, users will earn revenues from shared videos.

What programming paradigm is ideal for this kind of web site, and why ??

for DB, I'm using a MySQLi OOP Class.

Comment: What car should I buy? I need it to go from home to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you meant "OOP or Procedural", but regardless, that's the wrong question to ask.

**Choose a [framework](http://phpframeworks.com) and use it** . It doesn't matter which, they're all better than the alternative, *not* using a framework.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I chosen Yii Framework :)